# Capture NFC Tag only one time withDispatch System

Tags: android, tags, nfc, dispatch

i have an application Android for read a specified tag nfc format.

My activity only is open when that specified tag is readed. But  the phone stays near of tag, the activity is always re-created and i only want to open the activity at first time.

What i can do you implement this solution?

thanks

Comment: I'm a little unsure of what you are asking. Do you want the app to open the first time it comes near a tag, and then to stay open? Do you want to close it and not have it starting up all the time? Do you want different apps to open?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable foreground dispatch once your activity is started, then your activity will receive intents directly while running in the foreground without being recreated.

See doco for NfcAdaptor, enableForegroundDispatch() method:

[enableForegroundDispatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch%28android.app.Activity,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.content.IntentFilter%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

At a high level you can implement "debouncing":

http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/electronics/debounce.html

Basically you'd keep a record of recently executed tag reads, and only follow up on new reads if a certain amount of time has expired for that same tag, or if the tag was never scanned before.

If there is some way for the activity to cooperate and let you know when it is complete, you could reset the counter when the activity finishes.